# Unable to cast object of type x to type y

Tags: c#

```
public void darkModeToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!darkmode)
        {
            foreach(TextBox b in this.Controls)
            {

            }
```

It says "Unable to cast object of 'System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.TextBox'.'

Comment: Try `in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>()`

Comment: That's because a `MenuStrip` is not, and does not inherit from, `TextBox`. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Not all the elements in the `Controls` collection are textboxes, that's why this fails.

Try:

```cs
foreach(object b in this.Controls)
   { 
       if (b is TextBox textBox)
       {
       // use textBox...
       }
   }
```